# PHP 8.1, ошибка при установке sqlsrv и pdo_sqlsrv

Tags: php, linux, sql-server, debian, sqlsrv

Имеется сервер Debain 11 на котором установлен SQL SERVER и PHP 8.1
Необходимо установить необходимые расширения (sqlsrv и pdo_sqlsrv), при попытке установить одно из них я получаю ошибку:

```
/usr/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.la: No such file or directory
libtool:   error: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make: *** [Makefile:254: pdo_sqlsrv.la] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Пробовал удалять и устанавливать `libtool`, пробовал менять версию PHP с 7.4 и до более новых версий, пробовал удалять кэш и временные пакеты. Данная ошибка появляться в любом случаи, чтобы я не пробовал делать. `ChatGPT` не помогает :)
Какие могут быть возможные решения проблемы?

PS. Так же при попытке вручную скомпилировать расширение получаю ошибку:

```
libtool: warning: library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.la' was moved.
libtool: warning: library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.la' was moved.
libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/conn.o .libs/util.o .libs/init.o .libs/stmt.o shared/.libs/core_conn.o shared/.libs/core_results.o shared/.libs/core_stream.o shared/.libs/core_init.o shared/.libs/core_stmt.o shared/.libs/core_util.o shared/.libs/FormattedPrint.o shared/.libs/localizationimpl.o shared/.libs/StringFunctions.o   -lstdc++ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so  -g -O2 -Wl,-z -Wl,now   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,sqlsrv.so -o .libs/sqlsrv.so
libtool:   error: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make: *** [Makefile:251: sqlsrv.la] Error 1
```

Comment: Ну а пакет `libltdl-dev` у тебя установлен?

Comment: @donRumata да, конечно. Все необходимые зависимости установлены, пробовал так же разные версии зависимостей.

Comment: Тебе чё в итоге надо? Пых 81 и мсскуль? Или ещё чё-то?

Comment: PHP 8.1 c расширениями для SQL SERVER. Решил проблему путем установки всего в Docker контейнер.
Что странно, ведь на других серверах без проблем устанавливается PHP и необходимые расширения для SQL SERVER.

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп. Так это всё происходит внутри докер контейнера? Или докер - как конечное средство решения? Изначально - обычный хост на дебиане?

Comment: Докер - вынужденное решение, так как на Debian ничего не заработало. В любом случаи без Docker было бы лучше. На самом сервере так же есть проблемы с установкой msodbcsql17 (пробовал и другие версии). При попытке установить выдает сообщение `Errors were encountered while processing: путь к файлу. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`, пробовал как через APT, так и по инструции Microsoft. Ранее на сервере был установлен msodbcsql.

Comment: Ну чё могу сказать. На тестовую `ubuntu 20.04` у меня поехал и мсскуль и пхп (из ppa:ondrej/php). За Дебиан не скажу - не пользуюсь. Если есть возможность сменить хостовую ОС - лично я бы переехал.

Comment: Я бы тоже переустановил ОС,  так как на других серверах нет таких проблем (это именно локальная проблема на этом сервере, от части понял в чем кроется проблема, но не понимаю как её решить.) 
 На сервере множество проектов которые тяжело было собрать и запустить + бекапы на пару ТБ веса и различные файлы, переустановка не вариант :)

Comment: Ну тогда могу только посочувствовать.